# Using jq to parse and display multiple fields in a json serially

Tags: json, jq

I have this Json

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "first": "Stevie",
            "last": "Wonder"
        },
        {
            "first": "Michael",
            "last": "Jackson"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using jq I'd like to display first and last name serially. Like so -

```
Stevie Wonder
Michael Jackson
```

This is how far I have gotten -

```
jq '.users[].first, .users[].last'
```

But it displays

```
"Stevie"
"Michael"
"Wonder"
"Jackson"
```

Notice the following:

1. The double quotes that I do not want.
2. The carriage return that I do not want.
3. It's jumbled up. My query displays all the first names first, and then all the last names. However, I want first-last, first-last pair.

Answer (score 689):

I recommend using String Interpolation:

```
jq '.users[] | "\(.first) \(.last)"'
```

We are piping down the result of `.users[]` to generate the string ".first .last" using string interpolation. `\(foo)` syntax is used for string interpolation in `jq`. So, for the above example, it becomes "Stevie Wonder" (`".users[].first .users[].second"` working elementwise) and "Michael Jackson".

jq reference: [String interpolation](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C%28foo%29)

Comment: this is far better if your data are numbers

Comment: An explanation of the syntax would make this answer more useful.

Comment: A good answer should never just have an explanation in a link. Anything can happen to the website that is linked, and then people are left copying code that they don't understand.

Comment: Add `-r` switch if you don't want the output to be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: to append name or id with value `jq '.[] | "id=\(.id) name=\(.name)"')`

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! just what  was looking for.

Answer (score 375):

You can use [addition](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Addition) to concatenate strings.

> **Strings** are added by being joined into a larger string.

```
jq '.users[] | .first + " " + .last'
```

The above works when both `first` and `last` are string. If you are extracting different datatypes(number and string), then we need to convert to equivalent types. Referring to [solution on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46674867/979772). For example.

```
jq '.users[] | .first + " " + (.number|tostring)'
```

Comment: To eliminate the JSON quotation marks, invoke jq with the -r option, e.g. jq -r '.users[] | .first + " " + .last'

Comment: +1, but for my use case, I'm trying to format two numbers onto the same row. This approach fails because it can't add `" "` to a number. Eric's answer gives a better result for this case.

Comment: @Synesso: `(.numA|tostring) + " " + (.numB|tostring)` should work.  Or use string interpolation instead: `"\(.numA) \(.numB)"`.

Comment: When I did `jq '.users[] | .first + " " + .last'`, it worked very well, but caused a newline between the value of `.first` and `.last`. I changed the `" "` to `"@"` and then did a `sed 's/@/ /g'` on the output to get "John Smith" as the output. Something like this: `jq '.users[] | .first + "@" + .last' | sed 's/@/ /g'`

Answer (score 78):

```
jq '.users[]|.first,.last' | paste - -
```

Comment: this one allows to print array-fields with good formatting, unlike the other string-centric answers. thx

Answer (score 75):

In addition to what others have suggested, I think that two options are worth mentioning.

#### Print as CSV/TSV

```sh
$ cat file.json | jq -r '.users[] | [.first, .last] | @tsv'
Stevie  Wonder
Michael Jackson
```

```sh
cat file.json | jq -r '.users[] | [.first, .last] | @csv'
"Stevie","Wonder"
"Michael","Jackson"
```

The first expression, `.users[]`, unnests the objects from the outer-most array as in the code given in the question. The next expression, `[.first, .last]`, creates a new array of the values for each input object, and the final expression uses the built-in functions `@tsv` and `@csv` to print all input arrays as tab-separated and comma-seperated values, respectively.

#### Print as JSON values

Similarly, it is possible to construct JSON values again, which is interesting if you just want to keep a subset of the fields:

```sh
$ cat file.json | jq -c '.users[] | {first}'
{"first":"Stevie"}
{"first":"Michael"}
```

Answer (score 20):

my approach will be (your json example is not well formed.. guess thats only a sample)

```
jq '.Front[] | [.Name,.Out,.In,.Groups] | join("|")'  front.json  > output.txt
```

returns something like this

```
"new.domain.com-80|8.8.8.8|192.168.2.2:80|192.168.3.29:80 192.168.3.30:80"
"new.domain.com -443|8.8.8.8|192.168.2.2:443|192.168.3.29:443 192.168.3.30:443"
```

and grep the output with regular expression.

Comment: I wonder what this has to do with the question...? Also — why do you claim that the JSON example given by the OP is 'not well formed'? It looks great to me — and to syntax-checking tools, like, aye, `jq` itself. Also: can you show the contents of `front.json?

Comment: The comment was made in 2020, and someone edited the question in 2021. What you are seeing is the latest version of the question.

Answer (score 18):

This will produce an array of names

```
> jq '[ .users[] | (.first + " " + .last) ]' ~/test.json

[
  "Stevie Wonder",
  "Michael Jackson"
]
```

Answer (score 17):

While both of the above answers work well if key,value are strings, I had a situation to append a string and integer (jq errors using the above expressions)

Requirement: To construct a url out below json

```
pradeep@seleniumframework>curl http://192.168.99.103:8500/v1/catalog/service/apache-443 | jq .[0]
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   251  100   251    0     0   155k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  245k
{
  "Node": "myconsul",
  "Address": "192.168.99.103",
  "ServiceID": "4ce41e90ede4:compassionate_wozniak:443",
  "ServiceName": "apache-443",
  "ServiceTags": [],
  "ServiceAddress": "",
  "ServicePort": 1443,
  "ServiceEnableTagOverride": false,
  "CreateIndex": 45,
  "ModifyIndex": 45
}
```

Solution:

```
curl http://192.168.99.103:8500/v1/catalog/service/apache-443 |
jq '.[0] | "http://" + .Address + ":" + "\(.ServicePort)"'
```

Comment: note that escaping the closing parenthesis is not needed, and would err.

Comment: @nymo: That's not escaping. `\(...)` is string interpolation. Here it turns numeric `.ServicePort` into string.  Interpolation could be used in place of the `+` signs to make this solution shorter.

Answer (score 6):

I got pretty close to what I wanted by doing something like this

```
cat my.json | jq '.my.prefix[] | .primary_key + ":", (.sub.prefix[] | "    - " + .sub_key)' | tr -d '"'
```

The output of which is close enough to yaml for me to usually import it into other tools without much problem. (I am still looking for a way to basicallt export a subset of the input json)

Comment: This sort of works in my case, just drop the  | tr -d '"' at the end, and add -r option to jq.