# How do I use jq to convert number to string?

Tags: json, jq

Given the following jq command and Json:

```
jq '.[]|[.string,.number]|join(": ")' <<< '
[
  {
    "number": 3,
    "string": "three"
  },
  {
    "number": 7,
    "string": "seven"
  }
]
'
```

I'm trying to format the output as:

```
three: 3
seven: 7
```

Unfortunately, my attempt is resulting in the following error:

> jq: error: string and number cannot be added

How do I convert the number to string so both can be joined?

Answer (score 112):

The jq command has the [tostring](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#tostring) function.  It took me a while to learn to use it by trial and error.  Here is how to use it:

```
jq -r '.[] | [ .string, .number|tostring ] | join(": ")' <<< '
[{ "number": 9, "string": "nine"},
 { "number": 4, "string": "four"}]
'
nine: 9
four: 4
```

Comment: Thank you very helpful, I find jq hard to use and poorly documented so these examples really help.

Answer (score 72):

An alternative and arguably more intuitive format is:

```
jq '.[] | .string + ": " + (.number|tostring)' <<< ...
```

Worth noting the need for parens around `.number|tostring`.

Comment: For my use case I had to keep the parentheses to prioritize things. It's better to keep them for general use cases.

Comment: Thank you! I found this working for me too for concat purposes, after spending hours trying in vain to make sense of jq's horribly poor documentation! (and agreed, this is more intuitive than the answer above it.)

Answer (score 17):

For such simple case [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%28foo%29)'s implicit casting to string will do it:

```jq
.[] | "\( .string ): \( .number )"
```

See it in action on [jq‣play](https://jqplay.org/s/o3ki4PNtPo).

Comment: @Ярослав Рахматуллин, that's not useless escapes. That's jq's string interpolation syntax. Ruby has [`"#{ 1 + 2 }"`](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFhBKSk1Lb8oVUG5WsFQQVvBSKFWITGtJLVI6f9/AA), Groovy has [`"${ 1 + 2 }"`](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P@/oCgzr0RDKSk1Lb8oVUGlWsFQQVvBSKFWITGtJLVISfP/fwA), jq has [`"\( 1 + 2 )"`](https://tio.run/##yyr8/18pKTUtvyhVIUZDwVBBW8FIQVMhMa0ktUjp//9/@QUlmfl5xf918wA).

Comment: btw, Swift has the same string interpolation syntax