# Merge two arrays into a single object with jq

Tags: json, merge, key, jq

I'm trying to use jq to parse a NOAA data feed into just the values I need:

http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?FcstType=json&lat=39.56&lon=-104.85

I'm able to (separately) extract the two arrays I'm looking to combine:

```
$ cat noaa.json | jq .time.startPeriodName
[
  "Today",
  "Tonight",
  "Friday",
  "Friday Night",
  "Saturday",
  "Saturday Night",
  "Sunday",
  "Sunday Night",
  "Monday",
  "Monday Night",
  "Tuesday",
  "Tuesday Night",
  "Wednesday"
]

$ cat noaa.json | jq .data.weather
[
  "Mostly Sunny",
  "Mostly Cloudy",
  "Mostly Sunny",
  "Partly Cloudy",
  "Slight Chance Showers",
  "Slight Chance Snow Showers",
  "Slight Chance Snow Showers then Mostly Sunny",
  "Mostly Clear",
  "Mostly Sunny",
  "Partly Cloudy",
  "Mostly Sunny",
  "Partly Cloudy",
  "Mostly Sunny"
]
```

I'd like to combine the two arrays together into a single object like this:

```
{ 
   "Today": "Mostly Sunny",
   "Tonight": "Mostly Cloudy",
   ...
   "Wednesday": "Mostly Sunny"
}
```

I'd be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction. I feel like the answer is probably in the `map` operator, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, `map` is a good way to go.  The key here is to use it with `transpose/0`, which can be used as though it were a "zip" function:

```
 [.time.startPeriodName, .data.weather]
 | transpose
 | map( {(.[0]): .[1]})
```

The output begins as follows:

```
[
  {
    "Today": "Mostly Sunny"
  },
  {
    "Tonight": "Mostly Cloudy"
  },
  ...
```

So, to produce a single JSON object, simply add the `add` filter to the pipeline.

Comment: This is helpful. Is there a way I can run `transpose` and `map` so that I end up with a single object instead of an array of objects? or perhaps another transformation that can merge this resulting array into a single object?

Comment: Ah, I added `| add` to the end and got what I wanted.

Comment: Here's an example that references a path to get to the initial array. `jq ".results[0].result.tag | [.classes, .probs] | transpose | map( {(.[0]): .[1]} ) | add"` myinput.txt

Comment: The array from which I got my object keys was of the `number` type, I simply used `.[0]|tostring` inside the map (e.g. pipe to `tostring`) following [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35365769/how-do-i-use-jq-to-convert-number-to-string)

Comment: Another option to build a dict from a list of pairs is `map({key: .[0], value: .[1]}) | to_entries`