# Build a Json in Bash with two arrays

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

I actually have 2 arrays in bash that contains string values.
Something like that :

```
Array1=(Kevin Paul)
Array2=(OK DANGER)
```

I would like to create a json with 2 attributes, something like that if possible

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "nom":"Kevin",
         "status":"OK"
      },
      {
         "nom":"Paul",
         "status":"Danger"
      }
   ]
}
```

I read a lot speaking about JQ that i alreay use for my arrays, but no one speak about something like i want :(

One of my test ( that does not respond to what i would like ) :

```
declare -a test_array
declare -a test_array2
test_array=(apple orange lemon)
test_array2=(DANGER OK WARNING)
echo ${test_array[0]}

echo '['
printf '{"CVEC": "%s", "LVL" : "%s"},\n' "${test_array[@]}, ${test_array2[@]}" | sed '$s/,$//'
echo ']'

Display 

[
{"CVEC": "apple", "LVL" : "orange"},
{"CVEC": "lemon, DANGER", "LVL" : "OK"},
{"CVEC": "WARNING", "LVL" : ""}
]
```

Comment: The reason to use `jq` is that it ensures valid JSON no matter *what* values are stored in the arrays. A pure `bash` approach requires you to do all the examination of the values to ensure things that need to be escaped are handled properly.

Comment: Yes sure, but i don't have found anything for bash and build of json that respond to this :(

Comment: That's because `bash` doesn't have a built-in way to safely process produce JSON.

Comment: It seems you are looking for a zip function. eg. https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/609

Comment: No sry, not at all what i need

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41045659/10971581 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/30721317/10971581 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/17403498/10971581

Comment: Also: https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Loop_over_multiple_arrays_simultaneously#UNIX_Shell

Comment: @jhnc: looks very deprecated ressource

Comment: @jhnc `zip` would work if you already had JSON arrays; the trouble is safely converting a `bash` array to a JSON array in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a *template engine*: `perl`'s `Template::Toolkit` command line tool: `tpage`:

## Files

header:

```
{
   "results":[
```

footer:

```
   ]
}
```

file.tpl (template):

```
    {
        "nom": "[% x1 %]",
        "status": "[% x2 %]"
    }[% sep %]
```

## Bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

arr1=( Kevin Paul  )
arr2=( OK danger )

{
    cat header
    for i in "${!arr1[@]}"; do
        ((i==${#arr1[@]}-1)) && sep='' || sep=','
        tpage --define x1="${arr1[i]}" \
              --define x2="${arr2[i]}" \
              --define sep=$sep file.tpl
    done
    cat footer
} | tee file.json
```

## Validation

```
$ jq . file.json
{
  "results": [
    {
      "nom": "Kevin",
      "status": "OK"
    },
    {
      "nom": "Paul",
      "status": "danger"
    }
  ]
}
```

## Package

For debian and debian like:

```
apt install libtemplate-perl
```

Via CPAN:

```
cpan -i Template::Toolkit
```

Check http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/tools/tpage.html

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
paste <(printf "%s\n" "${Array1[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${Array2[@]}") |
    jq -nRc '{ results: [inputs] | map(split("\t") | { nom: .[0], status: .[1] }) }'
```

produces

```
{"results":[{"nom":"Kevin","status":"OK"},{"nom":"Paul","status":"DANGER"}]}
```

This assumes that the elements of your arrays do not have tabs or newlines in them. It uses `paste` to generate pairs of corresponding array elements, separated by tabs, one pair per line, and then uses `jq` to create the JSON output from that.

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to stick with a non-`jq` solution - and chepner's comments about needing to validate the array entries is not an issue for **this** situation - one idea would be to loop through the array indices.

Test data:

```
$ declare -a test_array=(apple orange lemon)
$ typeset -p test_array
declare -a test_array=([0]="apple" [1]="orange" [2]="lemon")

$ declare -a test_array2=(DANGER OK WARNING)
$ typeset -p test_array2
declare -a test_array2=([0]="DANGER" [1]="OK" [2]="WARNING")
```

A simple loop through the indices (0,1,2):

```
sfx=','                                                   # default printf suffix is a comma

for (( i=0 ; i<${#test_array[@]} ; i++ ))
do
    (( ${i} == ( ${#test_array[@]} - 1 ) )) && sfx=''     # clear suffix for last pass through loop

    printf '{"CVEC": "%s", "LVL" : "%s"}%s\n' "${test_array[${i}]}" "${test_array2[${i}]}" "${sfx}"
done
```

Which generates the following:

```
{"CVEC": "apple", "LVL" : "DANGER"},
{"CVEC": "orange", "LVL" : "OK"},
{"CVEC": "lemon", "LVL" : "WARNING"}
```