# Parsing stringified Json using shell

Tags: json, linux, shell, command

I have a Json in a varible $MYVAR like this :

```
{
"Name": "somename",
"MyField": "{\"mysubfield1\":\"value1\",\"mysubfield2\":\"value2\"}",
"OtherField" : "Othervalues"
...
}
```

**My constraint - I cannot use the jq parser.**
How can i parse `MyField` when it's a stringified Json ? I want to extract each value of the subfields - `value1` and `value2` and store in variables. Is there a direct approach /plain shell commands?

Comment: I assume you meant `jq`, not `jp`. If you can't use that, I think you're in trouble. `bash` doesn't have very powerful string processing builtins.

Comment: And parsing JSON is not trivial, you have to deal with escape sequences and nested elements. You should always use a pre-written parser or you won't handle all the corner cases properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using jq to parse and display multiple fields in a json serially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28164849/using-jq-to-parse-and-display-multiple-fields-in-a-json-serially)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'll be able to install jq. Even if I do, how do I take out the \" to make it a normal parsable json?

Comment: If you can't use `jq`, use a language with a JSON parser like `perl` or `python`, not shell.