# Not able to create ENV variable using API token

Tags: api, gitlab, continuous-integration, postman, gitlab-api

I was trying to automate creating ENV variables in CI/CD by using API commands, but unfortunately getting 401 Unauthorized error.

Earlier I used to do this in same way and was able to do it.
But now it’s throwing an error, could anyone please help me to find out.

Command:

```
curl --request POST --header “PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>” \
  “https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1/variables” --form “key=NEW_VARIABLE” --form “value=new value”
```

Please look into the error message:

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

The "[Create a variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html#create-a-variable)" API call indeed looks like:

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" \
 "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1/variables" --form "key=NEW_VARIABLE" --form "value=new value"
```

(make sure to use the right double-quotes `"` instead of `“`)

Double-check the ID of the project (in your case "1") and make sure the user authenticated with your token has the [right permissions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html#gitlab-cicd-permissions):

They must be "maintainer" or "owner", in order to have the right to "Manage project-level CI/CD variables".

---

Example, using a [Personal Access Token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) with `api` scope, starting with `glpat-` (`glpat-xxxxxxx`), I can first [list my projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39572304/6309) ([using `jq`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31418194/6309)):

`curl -XGET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: glpat-xxxx" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/owned?=true"|jq ".[]  | \"\(.id) \(.path_with_namespace)\""`

That allows me to find the project id

I can then list variables for an existing project:

`curl -XGET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: glpat-xxxx" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<projectId>/variables"`

Result:

```
[]
```

I have none on that project.
I will set one with:

`curl -XPOST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: glpat-xxxx" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<projectId>/variables" --form "key=NEW_VARIABLE" --form "value=new value"`

Result:

```
{"variable_type":"env_var","key":"NEW_VARIABLE","value":"new value","protected":false,"masked":false,"environment_scope":"*"}
```

Let's double-check with:

`curl -XGET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: glpat-xxxx" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<projectId>/variables"`

Result:

```
[{"variable_type":"env_var","key":"NEW_VARIABLE","value":"new value","protected":false,"masked":false,"environment_scope":"*"}]
```

It does work.

---

The [OP Anirban Das](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17938874/c) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73904107/not-able-to-create-env-variable-using-api-token/73904712#comment130521108_73904712) an issue with how [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) was used:

> Actually in the body of Postman, select '`form`', there I had mentioned directly key name in the `Key` section and value in the `Value` section.
> But that was not correct.
>
> In the `Key` section, we need to mention "`key`" and key name should be in `Value` section.
> Similarly "`value`" in key section and it's value in `Value` section.
>
> Once this worked, you will see "`</>`" icon in right navigation pane, which will provide you corresponding `curl` command

Comment: Yes, I have given correct project ID and used double quote as well (""). PFA screenshot. Also, in this project I am owner.

Comment: I tried to call API from Postman, there i am getting "error: key is missing, value is missing" error.

Comment: @AnirbanDas That soulds like your potman query did not send the form values.

Comment: yes. can you pls try from end and show me how it's behaving @VonC

Comment: @AnirbanDas I just tested the command. It does work. I have edited the answer to include an example.

Comment: still not working for me, looks like something missing still. Can you pls let me know whether there is any pre-requisites to execute API commands apart from personal access token. @VonC

Comment: @AnirbanDas the PAT (Personal Access Token) is the main prerequisite, provided it authenticates you, and with the right scope (api). Is your PAT starting with `glpat-`?

Comment: yes. even I worked on POST API earlier, then worked fine, but not sure why not working now. GET is working from Postman, but not with cURL

Comment: @AnirbanDas Do you have a `~/.curlrc` file? A proxy? What is you OS and OS version, shell and shell version?

Comment: finally able to do it from Postman and then copied corresponding curl command, that worked perfectly. Thanks much for your time :)

Comment: @AnirbanDas Great! What did you change/fix on postman in order to make that `curl` command work?

Comment: Actually in the body of Postman, select 'form', there I had mentioned directly key name in the Key section and value in the Value section. But that was not correct. In the Key section, we need to mention "key" and key name should be in value section. Similarly "value" in key section and it's value in value section.

Comment: once this worked, you will see "</>" icon in right navigation pane, which will provide you corresponding curl command.

Comment: @AnirbanDas Thank you so much for this feedback, I am sure it will help others. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.